# What is the "MTK Non-Framework LBS" app?

Tags: system-apps

I have a Blackview BV8800 running stock Doke OS 3.0 (their version of Android 11).  The "MTK Non-Framework LBS" app is non-removable so I assume it's part of the ROM from the manufacturer.  I can't find any information about it.  Is it dangerous? Should I disable it?

Comment: Please describe what is "This app" is? Best would be to provide the package name every Android app has as app names are language specific.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. A very quick research hints at [MediaTek (MTK)-based](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/sony-mobile-communications/mtk-non-framework-lbs-3/mtk-non-framework-lbs-3-1-0-release/mtk-non-framework-lbs-1-0-3-android-apk-download/) app for [Location Based Services (LBS)](https://www.techtarget.com/searchnetworking/definition/location-based-service-LBS). The package contains the word "[GNSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_navigation)" (Global Navigation Satellite System), but it's still a very rough guess.